# Cannot set height with percentages in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I wanted to build an alarm clock app in react, but i ran into a strange problem.
I have a container for all Alarm components, and i can't set height for them in percentages.
Is there any way to pass the height in percentages, instead of px/vh?

**Container**

```
function Container() {
return (
    <div className="container">
        <Alarm />
        <Alarm />
        <Alarm />
    </div>
)
```

}

**Container Styles**

```
.container{
  position: absolute;
  top: 7%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 90%;
  min-height: 60vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

**Alarm.js**

```
function Alarm() {

    return (
        <div className="alarm">
            quack quack
        </div>
    )
}
```

**Alarm Styles**

```
.alarm{
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;

  &:not(:first-child){
    margin-top: 50px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For percentage height to work, height of parent should be determinable but in your case, height of `.container` depends on it's children.
For percentage height of `.alarm` components to work, provide height to `.container` element

```js
function Alarm() {

  return ( 
    <div className = "alarm" >
      quack quack
    </div>
  )
}

function Container() {
  return (
    <div className = "container" >
      <Alarm />
      <Alarm />
      <Alarm />
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render( <Container /> , document.querySelector('#root'))
```

```css
.app {
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 7%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 90%;
  min-height: 60vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #ffff0088; /* only to visually distinguish */
  height: 300px; /* <-- Changed */
}

.alarm {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
  background-color: #0000ff88; /* only to visually distinguish */
}

.alarm:not(:first-child) {
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='root' />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think they might a few things causing this

1. The styles of the parent container ( containing everything )

- you could give it a `position of relative` and a height in ```px/vh``
  and then that 100% will work.

Comment: It actually worked, when i changed min-height to height, and I didn't had to change position to relative, and height could be passed in vh, but still Thank You for your answer!